# Ford 6000 CD radio code locked

Tags: ford, audio, code, unlock

I have a 2009 Ford with the following radio ID: V023619 can anyone tell me the code to unlock?  Thanks

Comment: Take the radio serial number and your VIN to a Ford dealer, they should be able to sort you out, there may be a charge or may not. Have you checked the handbook or is there a tag on the keyring?

Comment: There are plenty of web sites which can give you the code for modern radios (and 2009 is certainly modern enough) - but you usually have to pay a few dollars to get it. If you search motoring forums, you might find one where a member who works for a dealership will give you the code for free - but don't ask whether or not that is legal! When you have got the code, write it on the metal case of the radio with a marker pen, so it will never be forgotten again.

Comment: This trick works on some Fords - Jaguar with radios up to 2009, but may not help you... Enter any code 3 times so that the display shows "PLEASE WAIT" , Then
Simultaneously press ">>" "PTY" "A.MEM" should only take 2 or 3 seconds and the radio turns on.

Comment: This is not within site scope because it is not maintenance or repair, it is a phone call/visit to the dealership

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site was useful - http://www.freefordradiocode.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1617&p=42282#p42282.

To Rory Alsop that commented above, this was a maintenance question! I swapped the battery on my car yesterday and wished to get my radio working again.  The whole point of this site is to empower people to repair and maintain their vehicles using the free knowledge and help of others and avoid dealerships!